# After upgrade from ubuntu 12 to ubuntu 16, printer prints od wrong side of a paper

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, printing

I have multiple workstations with same setup: Ubuntu12 and Lexmark laser monochrome printer. 
After upgrading to Ubuntu 16, paper in the tray needs to be turned in another direction than usual. 
I've checked CUPS settings and they are exactly same in both versions of Ubuntu.
This is Obviously OS related, rather than printer related. 
Anyone has any idea how this settings is called or how to revert changes back to the old settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, figured, its "Page orientation". When typing system-config-printer into terminal I am able to change orientation. No idea why is that changed when I upgraded to Ubuntu16

[image]